# How to pop up a message window in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have to pop up a message in Qt when a particular test case is executed. Since I am a beginner in Qt, I do not want to risk trying with a qml...

How can I do it (directly in .cpp file) without creating a qml file?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you want to display a simple message, you can use a [QMessageBox::information](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/Qt/QMessageBoxinformation.htm).

Following the provided link, you can call a message box of that type this way:

```
QMessageBox::information( 
    this, 
    tr("Application Name"), 
    tr("An information message.") );
```

**Edit:** Since this question had a lot of visits during these years, I just wanted to include the other types of message for the sake of information (again, taken by the link above):

```
QMessageBox::warning( 
    this, 
    tr("Application Name"), 
    tr("A warning message.") );

QMessageBox::critical( 
  this, 
  tr("Application Name"), 
  tr("A critical message.") );

switch( QMessageBox::question( 
            this, 
            tr("Application Name"), 
            tr("An information message."), 

            QMessageBox::Yes | 
            QMessageBox::No | 
            QMessageBox::Cancel, 

            QMessageBox::Cancel ) )
{
  case QMessageBox::Yes:
    qDebug( "yes" );
    break;
  case QMessageBox::No:
    qDebug( "no" );
    break;
  case QMessageBox::Cancel:
    qDebug( "cancel" );
    break;
  default:
    qDebug( "close" );
    break;
}
```